# Get result of difference of two columns in a matrix in third column

Tags: powerbi-desktop

[image]

Above is a matrix in PowerBI that displays the amount and target amount for various divisions. I want to calculate the different between actual amount and target amount and display it in a third column in the matrix. I tried creating a column that calculates the difference between these two columns in the data table. But the data displayed in the matrix is not what I wish for it to be. I want the matrix to display the difference between the target and actual amount based on the values in the matrix only (which are derived based on certain filters applied). I do not want to get the difference of all the values in the dataset.

I am completely new to PowerBI and any help for the same would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use calculate. The value is the result of the expression evaluated in a modified filter context. That means in your current filter/row context.

```
diff = calculate([Target] - [Amount])
```

Comment: Suppose my target amount is in another table that is connected to this dataset using the division as unique identifier. Is there a way to calculate the difference?

Comment: If you have a relationship in your model between these table, that you don't need any additional change. Try this calculation. Eventually post your model  (screenshot - table with the relation) and describe the issue.